# How to get the text from mainframe using pyautoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am new to pyAutoGUI. I am trying to automate a screen and get the text of it. Can someone please let me know the code for it.

```
**import autoit**
import time
import pyautogui
from p3270 import P3270Client
from py3270 import Emulator
pid = autoit.run(f'path of exe')
time.sleep(10)
terminal_icon_position = (14, 5)
pyautogui.write("VC99")
pyautogui.press("TAB")
time.sleep(3)*
```

Comment: you need to extract text from screen, right? for this you need to perform OCR by caputring images of the screen at required intervals. you can check out documentation of libraries like pytesseract.

Comment: Hi Ishaan, Thank you for replying. I do not want to use the teserract one as it does provide the correct result. I have already tried it using Java. Please suggest something else.